# Redirect in React Router not working when I click from Users to Post

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
    <Route path="posts" element={<Posts />} />
    <Route path="" element={<Redirect to="/users" />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

I've just upgraded to React Router v6 and my Redirect isn't working. I'm a beginner and just started learning React, it's a bit hard for me to wrap my head around it, thanks for any help

Comment: do history.push('/users')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With React Router v6 you can't use `<Redirect>` anymore, you'll need to use `<Navigate>` and specify the `replace` prop (*if you want to redirect instead of just navigate*):

- [Navigate - React Docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate)
- [Redirect Default or 404 Routes with React Router v6](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/redirect-routes-with-react-router)

```js
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="users" element={<Users />} />
    <Route path="posts" element={<Posts />} />
    <Route path="" element={<Navigate to="/users" replace />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: thank you man a lot, IT WORKS !!! I was trying to figure this out, WOW this was a fast, amazing community here!

Comment: @Nick you're welcome! Sometimes an easy fix :)